# 220V AC to 220V DC rectifier bridge with Zener diode

Tags: rectifier, bridge-rectifier, electricity

I've made a rectifier bridge for converting 220V AC (supplied to mains in India) to 220V DC using 1N5408 Zener diode.

Can you please tell me whether it will successfully work out?

I will attach a resistance of 1000ohm on the DC side, as the maximum current is 3A.

A picture of the circuit is attached.

[image]

Comment: Gee, I really don't think that you should be doing this. First of all, I looked up this type 1N5408 diode and it's not a Zener diode at all. It's a rectifying diode. The fact that you think that it's a Zener diode or that a Zener diode is appropriate for this application is disturbing. Secondly , the fact that you think that it's OK to stick a 100 ohm resistor across a 200 volt DC bridge because the diodes can handle 3A but you don't even mention how many watts the resistor is rated for indicates that you aren't aware of all the dangers here.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: After seeing your comment, I contacted the ones who had said that it was a zener diode, and now they say that it was a printing mistake, and they had corrected it long back. However, I intended to use it as a rectifying diode and not as a zener. I bought it because I couldn't find the normal diodes at that point of time. If it is a rectifying diode, it should serve my purpose.

Comment: And it's a 1/4 watt resistor.

Comment: @Qmechanic It would definitely be a better home.  The only reason I answered it here was to make sure a reasonable high voltage disclaimer appeared on the first answer, in case it was closed rather than moving it.

Comment: @WRICHIKBASU: "And it's a 1/4 watt resistor.". - It's a 1/4 watt, 1000 ohm resistor? If you attach such a resistor across 220 volts DC, the power dumped into the resistor will be V^2/R=48.4 Watts, which will exceed the power rating of your resistor by a factor of almost 200! (Actually, did you re-edit your question? I thought that you said it was a 100 ohm resistor, in which case you would have exceeded the power rating by a factor of almost 2000.)

Comment: Yes, I did edit it.

Comment: @Samuel Weir  True, it'll exceed the power rating. Let me think... what if I use a 180 kohm resistor of 2W? That'll fit, I believe, though the current will be very low. If you find any high power low resistance resistor,  please let me know.

Comment: I hope you don't aspire for Darwin Award. 1N5408 is not a Zener diode, it is a general purpose diode. If you are doing just bridge rectifier, what are you going to do with it? 220V AC means you will get 310V peaks. The idea of 1000ohm resistor connecting to 220V leads me to conclusion you shouldn't mess with 220V with this level of your knowledge!

Comment: Some good person please close this question: I'm done with it 

Comment: @WRICHIKBASU 220V is a bad way to learn. It can kill you. If you want to learn EE, start with low voltage first.

Comment: @Chupacabras You don't get cheap AC sources.

Comment: @YashasSamaga AC wall-wart transformers are pretty cheap and much safer to start off with.

Answer (score 5):

A few things.  First is my essential disclaimer which I use quite often on the Electronic stack exchange:

> If you have to ask Stack Exchange about a high voltage device, you probably shouldn't make it.  You should only rely on your own training and trusted sources.  You only get one heart, and you should not put it at risk because someone on the internet said it was safe.

220V is not a trivial thing.  The first thing I notice is that you are showing me a bunch of wires not enclosed in a safe plastic box.  When you plug this thing in, there's going to be 220V between open metal contacts.  That's a terribly great safety hazard.  I can only hope that you intended to correct this, and merely had the components out to make it easier to photograph them.

It appears your diodes are the correct size and they look to be in the correct orientation.

Note that you will not generate 220V DC with this setup.  You will generate a rectified signal which will be a half-sine-wave which peaks at 312V (if India is anything like the US, we provide the RMS voltage on our lines, not peak.  220V rms is 312V peak).  You will then need to use other components to filter that half-sine-wave into a reasonably flat signal.

Comment: Safety is a question, and I've enclosed this whole in a wooden box. If I get 312V signal, I can use a 1000ohm resistor to decrease the current to 0.312V.

Comment: Of course,  I'll attach safety devices like a fuse.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this device?  Are you trying to power something, or just trying to see if you can make a full-wave rectifier?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it to see whether I can make a full wave rectifier. If it succeeds, then I may use it in something else.

Comment: @WRICHIK Depending on how you define "succeeds", that can still be a terrible idea. Having exposed leads in a wooden box that you set and then forget about is an important fire hazard. Please heed the safety warning at the top of this post carefully.

Comment: Okay, I understand safety hazard, and problems with calculations. I could find a way, but I do not have resources to carry out the experiment at this point, so I'll carry it out later. But tell me: theoretically, will this work if I satisfy current and wattage problems, keeping in mind the safety? Meaning, will I get rectified full wave dc from ac using this circuit?

Comment: @WRICHIKBASU _"If I get 312V signal, I can use a 1000ohm resistor to decrease the current to 0.312V."_ - **Please stay away from mains electricity. You show a dangerous lack of understanding.**

Comment: Such a device does not provide any galvanic insulation from main power, touching a single part can cause injuries.